# Distinguishing between URIs vs. slugs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Unfortunately now I don't have any code to show because my question on the current stage is more a brainstorming rather than coding.

**Question**. I need to detect whether a given string can be a valid [**URI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) address like

> https://myserver.com/about/team

or

> ftp://myserver.com/foo/bar/whatever.txt

vs. a **slug**

> /about/team

or

> /foo/bar/whatever.txt

**Are regex the only solution that makes sense?** Is there any dedicated function in vanilla JS? Function would return `uri` for first two examples, `slug` for 3rd and 4th and for example `invalid` for anything else.

Comment: just check if it starts with `letters://`

Comment: that regex may fail with stuff like `www.wathever.com` I think?

Answer (score 0):

Just ping the server.

Here is a javascript API that does it from the client side -

https://github.com/jdfreder/pingjs

Set the logic to ping the address first and if it pings back, you know the address is exists and is good.